# Is it possible to capture the output of SHOW OPEN TABLES into a table?

Tags: mysql-5.6, mysql-5.7

I need to periodically capture the output of different SHOW commands in mysql, for example SHOW OPEN TABLES. I know I can use a cron job to do something, but I'd prefer to do it internally, if possible, like in a scheduled event.

I have been looking (but not finding) for something like:

- A way to capture the output to stdout in a variable
- A way to see if mysqld actually runs some SQL or procedures/functions to generate the output

I have found ["Show" Output Store Into Table](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/205121/show-output-store-into-table), but I don't think it is useful in my case.

In short, is there a way to capture the output of SHOW commands?

Comment: "capture the output to stdout" is conflicting with "I'd prefer to do it internally".

Comment: @GerardH.Pille "capture the output to stdout" is short for "capture the output that mysqld is going to deliver to the client, but before it actually sent off". Something comparable to "INSERT INTO ... SELECT ..."